# c# WPF ListView Displays either Grouping of Data, but not both

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a bound ListView on a Window and I've setup XAML to do grouping, but when I try to apply it I either get only data or grouping with no data. The XAML is as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvNav" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="331,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Customer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding serviceID}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="S/N" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding machineID}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.GroupStyle>

         <GroupStyle>
             <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                     <Setter Property="Template">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <ControlTemplate>
                                 <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                     <Expander.Header>
                                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                         </StackPanel>
                                     </Expander.Header>
                                 </Expander>
                             </ControlTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                     </Setter>
                 </Style>
             </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
         </GroupStyle>
     </ListView.GroupStyle>
 </ListView>
```

The code that loads the data is:

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<srsr> srsrs = _fa.srsrs;
srsrs.Load();

lvNav.ItemsSource = srsrs.Local;

CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvNav.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription pgd = new PropertyGroupDescription("stateID");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(pgd);
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something relatively simple here, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use the `MVVM` approach i.e. without code behind, you could use this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding PropertyOnYourVM}" x:Key="NameOfTheGrouping">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PropertyToGroupOn"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

you can then use it like this on your ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameOfTheGrouping}}">

<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource YourStyleNameHere}"/>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

But because you are NOT using MVVM you will have to do it in code behind.
BTW: you forgot `<ItemsPresenter />` in your xaml, which goes between `</Expander.Header>` and `</Expander>`

Comment: Thank you! Adding the <ItemPresenter /> solved the issue! Wow that was really irritating.

Comment: If you add a sample, then it should be a working one... you cannot set the "ContainerStyle" Property to a CollectionViewsource Object.....

Comment: actually you put the CollectionViewSorce in the Window.Resources, and bind the ItemsSource Property of the Listview to this. refer here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx)